# Is it possible to return value like this?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have a question about Python syntax, didnt found on the google :/
I trying to write universal function, for locators search on Selenium.

I have locators in locators.py, they looks like this:

```py
class LoginForm:
    email    = {'css': '#email'}
    password = {'css': ' #password'}
    login_button = {'css': '#submitLoginForm'}
```

and in base_page.py I have this:

```py
def __unify_locator(self,selector: dict):
    elif 'css' in selector.keys():
        return (By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector['css'])

def __element(self, selector: dict, index: int):
    return self.driver.find_elements((self.__unify_locator(selector)))[index]
```

As you can see, I trying to return from `__unify_locator` something like `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,selector['css'])`. I want to make it agile, because in the future I can use XPath or Link Text or e.t.c

Is it possible to return values like this ? case I got errors on execute that part of code

Comment: One problem right away: You are using elif, which can only come after an if. Just use an if instead of elif.

Comment: `elif 'css'` is not legal in Python.

Comment: If you can write a valid expression, Python can `return` it. It'.s not clear what the members of the tuple represent, but if they are valid expressions too, this should work. If you don't want to return a tuple, propably [edit] to clarify what you hope your expression should mean.

Comment: tnx, guys.  
 `self.driver.find_elements(*self.__unify_locator(selector))` works as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to return values like this ? case I got errors on execute that part of code

Yes, you can return a tuple like this. The error isn't because of the return, but because of how you use it. To separate the values in the tuple as parameters to another function, use the splat operator `*`:

```
self.driver.find_elements(*self.__unify_locator(selector))
                          ^ here
```

One suggestion: You can write your selectors directly as such a pair:

```
email = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email')
```

Then you don't need `__unify_locator()` at all:

```
self.driver.find_elements(*selector)
```

Alternatively, your selector can be a dict to provide context to the meaning of each value:

```
email = {
    'by': By.CSS_SELECTOR,
    'value': '#email',
}
```

Then use `**` instead of `*`:

```
self.driver.find_elements(**selector)
```

Finally, you cannot have `elif` without an `if`, but I think you just didn't post some of your code in `__unify_locator()`.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is likely simply that you are using `elif` instead of `if`. I don't know the rest of your setup, but it may work if you just do

```
if 'css' in selector.keys():
```

instead of using `elif`.

`elif` is short for else if. It goes after a different if statement, and will only be checked if the previous `if` condition evaluates to false. Since here you are only testing one condition, you should use `if`.

Since you say you want flexibility in the future, your next conditions could use `elif`, and would be entered if their condition is true **and** the if above them is false.

Comment: tnx man, 
forgot to fix "elif" after deleting some useless lines of code on stackoverflow :)